# How do I get wireless access in kali / ubuntu linux on macbook?

Tags: wifi, osx, drivers, kali-linux, broadcom

Im struggling trying to get Wifi working on a live kali Linux 2.0 or ubuntu 16 thumb drive on macbook pro. Wifi card doesnt show up in ifconfig or iwconfig of course.

my broadcomm chip is here.

```
en0:
  Card Type:    AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x134)
  Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
```

what boggles my mind is how Im supposed to do this because in order to run apt-get ANYTHING I need net connection.  have no ethernet port of course.

trying to manually find the right driver files and compile and install them is like pulling teeth with no clear explanation ive found yet.  can I really not run linux distros on a mbp?  thanks for any help.  If I can somehow download them manually and install offline I could try that

Comment: Please add the exact `bcm43xx`

Comment: Honestly it doesn't say and I've done some digging online trying to find my exact chip number but I am not able to.  If you know of a way that would be great MBP Retina late 2013 15"

Comment: what is the output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`?

Comment: Ok that gave more info:  Broadcom BCM4360  [14e4:43a0] (rev 03).  Subsystem: Apple device [106b:0134].  Multi media controller [0480]:  Broadcom corporation device [14e4:1570]

Comment: Because the driver isn't included on the 2 linux distro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the only solution is to buy an thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter and plug into a wired connection and run through the commands at this guide:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/pentestmac.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/kali-linux-broadcom-wireless-on-macbook/amp/

Pretty ridiculous just to get wifi working on an extremely common wifi chip.  Sigh.  Hopefully someone else can skip the headache and find this solution.